# Plotting the Divergence of a 3-D ODE

Tags: matlab, math, ode

Iam a newbie to the world of coding and I've started to work with codes recently.

Problem discription: I need to plot the divergence of a system (liu) that is described by a 3-D ODE with respect to the evolution of the system in time. The code is written by using MATLAB. In codes, I've described the necessary details of the dynamical system well and the divergence of the system is calculated in rectangular coordinate system, but Iam not able to get the desired output. Iam attaching the code down below.

```
    %%

    % Aim: To obtain the plot of 
    dissipativity (by calculating the divergence in rectangular coordinate system)for the system liu

    % Specify the system parameters
    %Specify the system topology
    %

    function liu
    t0 = 0; % Initial point
    tn = 100; % Terminal point
    Y0 = [2.2, 2.4, 38]; % Initial values
    Y  = [x, y, z]

    a = 16;b = 100;c = 2.5;k=1;h=4; % system parameters

    % Solve the equations for divergence. 

    divergence(dYdt, Y)

    % generating plot of divergence v/s time

    plot(t,divergence(dYdt, Y),'Color', [0.72,0.27,1.00]) 
    %plot(t,Y(:,2),'Color', [0.72,0.27,1.00])
    xlabel('t')
    ylabel('y')
    title('liu')
    hold on
    figure()


      function dYdt = liu(~,X)

dxdt =a*(X(2)-X(1)); % SYSTEM TOPOLOGY
dydt = b*X(1)-k*x(1)*x(3); % SYSTEM TOPOLOGY
dzdt = -c*X(3)+ h*X(1)*X(1); % SYSTEM TOPOLOGY
dYdt = [dxdt; dydt; dzdt];

      end
    end
    %
    %%
```

Comment: I would expect that you first compute the ODE solution with an ODE solver, and then evaluate the divergence of the vector field along that solution. I do not see a call to ode45 or ode15 or similar in your code.

Comment: Thankyou, I'll try that out.